# ZF: wrong links when using routing in bootstrap

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-route, zend-controller, zend-controller-router

The problem is when generating Zend_Navigation menu in the view all links have "/projects/add/" href. 
At the same time when "/projects/list/" is active all links are correct. 
The same if I deleted this route - all links are ok.

So, while "/projects/add/" href is active the problem is.

Part of code from bootstrap:

```
        $frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
        $router = $frontController->getRouter();

        $router->addRoutes(array(
            'AddProject' => new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('/projects/add/:key', array('module' => 'default', 'controller' => 'projects', 'action' => 'add', 'key' => '')),
        ));
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer I found [here](http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=69&t=1740)

I just added default at all menu items which hadn't  before. This is it...))